# Primefaces: Accessing the button on 'oncomplete' event in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces

I am using `p:dataTable`. There is a column which has a `p:commandbutton` **in each row**. I need to access that button in javascript on `oncomplete` event. what should i pass in the function `oncomplete="myFunction(attr)"` or is there any other way to access it?

Comment: I solved it by passing the rowIndex and colIndex to the function. And fetching my button by making an id from rowIndex, colIndex and commandButton id.

Comment: Answers belong in answers, not in comments. But I suspect you found a 'duplicate' somewhere in stackoverflow? If so, please mark it as such or create a real answer (but also improve the question then with real code (in [mcve] format) from before you found the answer)